# Grep: Single vs Double Quotes

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

I'm trying to understand the difference of single and double quotes in these particular situations:

```
egrep '^Za(za)+!$' *
```

returns `Zaza!` and `Zazazazaza!` (Which is what I want)

```
egrep "^Za(za)+!$" *
```

returns the ones I mentioned above but also `Zaaazazaaaa!`, `Zaza`, `Zazaza!Zazaza!`, `Za!`

From my understanding, double quotes take the meanings of the symbols like `+` into account, so why would the double quotes not work?

Comment: If you don't use _history expansion_ and don't want surprises like this, turn it off with `set +H`.  To keep it off automaticly, you may want to place this command in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!$` is a [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) that selects the last word from the previous command (so the result actually depends on that other command!).  Those are processed [inside double quotes but not inside single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).